# SBCL save-lisp-and-die: Can I set different names for executable and source file?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I can compile a lisp source to a self contained executable with overwriting source by binary file.
My call:

```
(sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die #P"test.lisp" :toplevel #'main :executable t)
```

It is working well. Is it possible to specify different names for source and exe and thus avoid overwriting of source?

Comment: The documentation is here: http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Function-sb_002dext-save_002dlisp_002dand_002ddie

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be confused about the arguments to `save-lisp-and-die`: the positional argument is the core file (memory image) or executable you are creating: it's entirely unrelated to the source files.  What you're doing is just calling that enormous binary file `test.lisp`.  In particular what you're *not* doing is loading `test.lisp`.

If you want to dump an executable you might typically do something like:

In `loadup.lisp`:

```
(in-package :cl-user)

(load (compile-file "my-big-program.lisp"))

(save-lisp-and-die "my-big-program"
                   :toplevel #'my-big-program
                   :executable t)
```

in `my-big-program.lisp`:

```
(in-package :cl-user)

(defun my-big-program ()
  (format t "~&Hello world~%")
  t)
```

Then do something like

```
$ sbcl --no-userinit --no-sysinit --load loadup.lisp
[...]
$ ./my-big-program
Hello world
$
```

Obviously you can put everything in one file, but this makes it hard to develop code as every time you load the sources Lisp quits, which is a bit undesirable.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I was not aware of these facts. Indeed I did a (load "test.lisp") prior to (save-lisp-file-compile) and did assume that the save command would read the source file. I have tried your solution and strted with compile-file what also worked.